# How to create Windows native compatible Zip files with non-ASCII filenames

Tags: java, windows, utf-8, filenames, non-latin

Our team has a program that generates PDFs written in Java. The PDFs, which may have non-ASCII filenames, are zipped using Apache Commons Compress. The zip files are then uploaded to S3 to be downloaded by Windows and Mac clients.

When unzipped on Mac using the native tools, the files are recreated with the correct filename. However, when trying to unzip using the native Windows UI tool, the filenames are created incorrectly.

The zip process is:

```
    import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
```

and I have add following code, it's still not working, display unreadable characters on Windows:

```
    zipFile.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    zipFile.setUseLanguageEncodingFlag(true);     
    zipFile.setCreateUnicodeExtraFields(ZipArchiveOutputStream.UnicodeExtraFieldPoli‌​cy.ALWAYS);
```

How can I create zip files that can be used by both Mac and Windows?

Comment: Yes, it's UTF8, and what version of windows? Not all windows use UTF8 for filenames encoding.

Comment: Windows 7, the filenames are utf-8 encoded, mac can show it correctly, but windows cannot, should I generate a different version of filenames just for windows or there is some way I can add self-describing meta data about encoding to filenames so that platform can infer accordingly?

Comment: how are you generating the utf non-ascii characters to use in the filename?

Comment: zipFile.putArchiveEntry(new ZipArchiveEntry(               filenameDeduper.getUniqueName(metadataModel.getFileName())));
I guess it's equal saying zipFile.putArchiveEntry(new ZipArchiveEntry( javaString))

Comment: try putting the filename to the console. Does it produce the expected non-latin characters or is it garbage? As far as I can see, unless somewhere in that function call one of those functions doesn't handle utf8 properly (which I believe utf8 is universal in java) then I'm at a loss. The only other thing I can think is that the OS is configed not to use UTF8 or display them. Try it on a different windows machine that you know handles utf8 properly. otherwise I'm at a loss.

Comment: as I have seen on my mac console, they looks fine

Answer (score 2):

According to Apache Commons Compress page:(https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html)

> Windows' "compressed folder" feature doesn't recognize any flag or extra field and creates archives using the platforms default encoding - and expects archives to be in that encoding when reading them.

and

> If Windows' "compressed folders" is your primary consumer, then your best option is to explicitly set the encoding to the target platform. You may want to enable creation of Unicode extra fields so the tools that support them will extract the file names correctly.

Therefore:

If you know that your Windows users are based in a limited region of the Earth and your filenames are limited to that region (e.g. all Latin), you could heed Apache's advice and define an 8bit code page for filename encoding, which would be respected by OS X's unzip. However, this would mean that it would not work on Windows machines in a different region or accidentally used a slightly different codepage (North American vs. Western Europe).

The sensible alternative would be to use an alternative archive tool on Windows and possibly an alternative archive format. Perhaps you could create self-extracting archives for Windows by prepending a suitable extraction tool to the zip file. For example, you can create a self-extracting 7zip archive in Java using the rough instructions here: http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/de8aa3c6

The pseudo format is:

```
7z.sfx + config.txt + your-created-archive.7z your-created-archive.exe
```

Where `7z.sfx` is a 7zip self-extracting executable "header" distributed with 7zip.

In response to comments in question:

> Windows uses UTF-16 for filenames and AFAIK uses UTF-16 in it's low level API, which Java calls. However, Windows console is very broken and doesn't quickly support UTF-8.
>
> (Java also uses UTF-16 internally for String objects)
>
> OS X enforces UTF-8 for filename encodings, so Java should also be respecting that when creating filenames.